# c++ varargs/variadic function with two types of arguments that repeat together (alternating)

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I can find examples of how to write variadic functions with one type that repeats like `StringFormat()` but I need to write one where two different types repeat alternating.

The usage needs to look like this:

```
MyFunc(stringVar, intVar1, doubleVar1);
MyFunc(stringVar, intVar1, doubleVar1, intVar2, doubleVar2, intVar3, doubleVar3, intVar4, doubleVar4);
```

where the function always has a string input and a minimum of one int and one double but where the int and double would repeat together.

If possible I also need a way to have the documentation tell you which arg type you're on.  Maybe the documentation generates automatically and just works but just in case there's something special you need to do please include that too or if it's not possible to have intellisense work for that please let me know.  Something like this maybe: ???

```
/// <summary>
/// MyFunc Summary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">Name description</param>
/// <param name="event1_id">ID for Event 1</param>
/// <param name="event1_value">Value for Event 1</param>
/// ...
/// <param name="eventN_id">ID for Event N</param>
/// <param name="eventN_value">Value for Event N</param>
/// <returns>return description</returns>
```

Comment: Simpler would be to have pair/struct to group ID and value. and then possibly `vector`/`initializer_list`.

Comment: intellisense doesn't handle SFINAE, so hard coded overloads might be an option for documentation/intellisense. You can then still forward to variadic solution.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Can you show an example implementation of this function? Also, what do you mean by "*have the documentation tell you which arg type you're on."*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can write the following function:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void MyFunc(std::string Var, Ts ...ts)
{
    // simple structure to store each pair of arguments
    struct Arg { int i; double d; }; 

    // checks narrowing conversions, 
    // and incorrect type/number of arguments
    std::array<Arg, sizeof...(Ts) / 2> arr { ts... };   

    // ensures at least one int and double argument
    static_assert(std::size(arr) > 1);  

    // ...
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E891oa).

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this by creating a type trait.  My first attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace {
    template <typename FIRST_EXPECTED, typename SECOND_EXPECTED,
              typename FIRST_ACTUAL,   typename SECOND_ACTUAL,
              typename ...Ts>
    struct repeating_pair {
        static constexpr bool value = repeating_pair<FIRST_EXPECTED, SECOND_EXPECTED,
                                                     FIRST_ACTUAL, SECOND_ACTUAL>::value &&
                                      repeating_pair<FIRST_EXPECTED, SECOND_EXPECTED,
                                                     Ts...>::value;
    };

    template <typename FIRST_EXPECTED, typename SECOND_EXPECTED,
              typename FIRST_ACTUAL,   typename SECOND_ACTUAL>
    struct repeating_pair<FIRST_EXPECTED, SECOND_EXPECTED, FIRST_ACTUAL, SECOND_ACTUAL> {
        static constexpr bool value = std::is_same_v<FIRST_ACTUAL, FIRST_EXPECTED> &&
                                      std::is_same_v<SECOND_ACTUAL, SECOND_EXPECTED>;
    };

}

int main() {
    std::cout << repeating_pair<int, double, int, double>::value << '\n'
              << repeating_pair<int, double, int, float>::value << '\n'
              << repeating_pair<int, double, int, double, int, double>::value << '\n'
              << repeating_pair<int, double, int, double, int, float>::value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This will give you a compile-time check that you have repeating types, and you can leverage that in `MyFunc`.

```
template <typename FIRST, typename SECOND, typename ...Ts>
void MyFunc(std::string stringVar, FIRST intVar1, SECOND doubleVar1, Ts ...ts) {
    static_assert(repeating_pair<int, double, FIRST, SECOND, Ts...>::value);
    // whatever your code does
}
```